# Kendo ui Calculated Columns with Batch Editing in Grids

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had kendo simple demo in kendo grid [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/AqoqElaP).

1. The `price` will change based on `quantity` value, the problem how do I get the default value back if the `quantity` change to `1`?
2. And How to make price column `editable:false`? (if set to true, price column not able to dynamic change) Any idea?

[full demo in dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AqoqElaP)

```js
save: function(e) {    
  if (e.values.hasOwnProperty("quantity")){
    var current_qty = e.values.quantity;
    var current_price = e.model.price;

    var totalPrice = current_price * current_qty;
    e.model.set('price', totalPrice);

    if(e.values.quantity == 1){
      console.log('set back to default value') ;
    }   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you set your columns with a calculated field and non editable.

```
columns: [
     { field: "quantity", title: "quantity", format: "{0:c}" },
     { field: "current_price", title: "current_price", format: "{0:c}" },
     { title: "totalPrice", template: "<span>#= quantity * current_price #</span>", editable: false }],
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-calculated-column-with-batch-editing) here that might help  and here [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AqoqElaP/2) (in case someone needed). Basically I created a dummy field and `save` event assign the total price.